# How do I use $_GET correctly to make return url for multiple parameters

Tags: php, get

Let's say my current URL page is

```
http://domain.com/listing.php?term=updated&page=7&more=new-user
```

In this page have a link to `users.php` looks like below.

```
<a href="http://domain.com/users.php?uid=10&term=updated&page=7&more=new-user">More</a>
```

On page `users.php` have a `back link` to `listing.php`

```
<a href="http://domain.com/listing.php?term=updated&page=7&more=new-user">Back</a>
```

The question is :-

How do I grab all variables such `term` `page` `more` `etc` on `users.php` to make sure when user click the `back` link will go to previous page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution would be to use JavaScript:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">Back</a>
```

Comment: Let's say on `users.php` have action like `CRUD`.